# как FancyBox растянуть в % по ширине?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Наткнулся на это:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/JS6HU/52/)
Там FancyBox растягивается по ширине в % от окна браузера.

У меня же код немного другой:

```
<!-- FancyBox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print $http_adr; ?>/fancybox/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php print $http_adr; ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php print $http_adr; ?>/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php print $http_adr; ?>/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.4.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 1020)
{
    //alert (document.documentElement.clientWidth);
    var screen_width=800;
}
else
{
    var screen_width=1000;
    //alert (document.documentElement.clientWidth);
}
</script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    //alert (screen_width);
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a.view_more").fancybox({
                'hideOnContentClick':   false,
                'zoomSpeedIn'       :   100,
                'zoomSpeedOut'      :   100,
                'overlayOpacity'    :   0.65,
                //'overlayColor'        :   'rgba(100,150,255, 0.6)',               
                'overlayColor'      :   '#2575c2',              
                'overlayShow'       :   true,
                'autoResize'        :   true,
                'imageScale'        :   false,
                'autoScale'         :   true,
                'frameHeight'       :   600, // высота окна, px(355px - по умолчанию)                   
                'frameWidth'        :   screen_width     // ширина окна, px (425px - по умолчанию)
                //'autoDimensions'  :   true //подгоняет размеры области просмотра к размеру элемента (с текстом не работает)


            });

        });
    </script>

<!-- end FancyBox -->
```

Пробовал вставить проценты `type: 'iframe',    width: '90%',` И не получается.
Как в моём случае (примере) растягивать FancyBox по ширине в %?

Comment: Я думаю без реального примера будет сложно, вот вставил ваш код и всё работает: http://jsfiddle.net/JS6HU/53/

Comment: @lampa, вы меня не поняли - мой код работает. Но вот я привёл пример выше с % в параметрах.
Т.е. хотел реализовать что-то вроде `'frameWidth':80%`, а оно не работает. Версия FancyBox - 1.2.4